# How to redirect http access to standard web url?

Tags: php, apache, http, url, lamp

let's assume there is a website : http://www.mywebsite.com 
In visitor log for http lot of different types of entries are found, such as :

```
1] www.mywebsite.com 
2] mywebsite.com
3] webadmin@mywebsite.com 
4] dummyuser@mywebsite.com 
and so on...
```

I'm finding a generic solution, which will re-direct all such requests to http://www.mywebsite.com

Also, is there any way to re-direct http request like webadmin@mywebsite.com/dummy.php to http://www.mywebsite.com

Note: I'm using LAMP environment.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way to redirect all request that contains `website.com`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} website\.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} website\.com
RewriteRule ^ http://www.mywebsite.com? [L,R=301]
```